# How can i open this razorpay action link popup in new tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, razorpay

[image]

I am trying to open this popup window in new tab. But I cannot find a proper way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I leave you an example of how to open dynamic file links

```
let oTag = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(oTag);
oTag.style = 'display: none';
oTag.href = oBlobURL;
oTag.target = '_blank';
oTag.click();
// Remove the blob after 10 minutes
setTimeout(() => {
     window.URL.revokeObjectURL(oBlobURL);
     oTag.remove();
}, (10 * 60 * 1000));
```